# SQL Server - How to Hint an Index on an Update command?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, hint

I'm trying to execute the following command to force an update to use a non-clustered index:

```
 UPDATE Flights 
 SET Airtime=5555678
 WHERE Distance=10000
 OPTION (TABLE HINT(Flights, INDEX (DistanceIndex)))
```

... and it's erroring:

> Msg 8724, Level 16, State 1, Line 75
>   Cannot execute query. Table-valued or OPENROWSET function 'Flights' cannot be specified in the TABLE HINT clause.

I can't find any clear advice on how the syntax should be properly formed inside the `TABLE HINT` statement.

Please can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try following:

```
UPDATE F
SET F.Airtime=5555678
FROM Flights F WITH (INDEX (DistanceIndex))
WHERE F.Distance=10000
```

or

```
UPDATE Flights
SET Airtime=5555678
FROM Flights -- this line is added to your initial query
WHERE Distance=10000
OPTION (TABLE HINT(Flights, INDEX (DistanceIndex)))
```

Comment: many thanks for your comments. Both the above methods worked for me, with identical impact on the execution plans. Kind regards, Jon

Answer (score 4):

@i-one's answer is correct and the recommended way.

You can also use

```
UPDATE F
SET    Airtime = 5555678
FROM   Flights F
WHERE  Distance = 10000 
OPTION (TABLE HINT(F, INDEX (DistanceIndex)))
```

[But the documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

> We recommend using the INDEX, FORCESCAN or FORCESEEK table hint as a
>   query hint only in the context of a plan guide.

Comment: @MartinSmith- many thanks for your comments. Appreciate that this approach rails against best practice - I was just interested to note the performance difference in the operation if I could force the use of a [less efficient] secondary index. I read further into the use of FORCESCAN and FORCESEEK, as i've not looked at these approaches. Kind regards, Jon